# TimeWithZone & Time.zone.now integration test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

In a controller method I set a user's variable `activation_sent_at` equal to `Time.zone.now` when an activation email is sent to that user. On the development server this seems to work (although time expressions in my application are 2 hours behind on the local time of my computer).

I want to include an integration test that tests whether `activation_sent_at` indeed gets set properly. So I included the line:

```
assert_equal @user.activation_sent_at, Time.zone.now
```

However, this produces the error:

```
No visible difference in the ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#inspect output.
You should look at the implementation of #== on ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone or its members.
```

I think it's suggesting to use another expression for `Time.zone.now` in my test. I've looked at different sources, including http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html, but am not sure what to do here. Any suggestions what could be causing this error?

**Additional info:** Adding `puts Time.zone.now` and `puts @stakeholder.activation_sent_at` confirms the two are equal. Not sure what generates the failure/error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The issue is that the 2 dates are very close to each other but not the same. You can use [`assert_in_delta`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_in_delta)

`assert_in_delta @user.activation_sent_at, Time.zone.now, 1.second`

For **RSpec**, a similar approach would be to use [`be_within`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers%3Abe_within):

`expect(@user.activation_sent_at).to be_within(1.second).of Time.zone.now`

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now` include milliseconds (when you do a simple `put` to print the time it doesn't show milliseconds). However, when you persist the timestamp in the database these milliseconds likely get lost unless the db field is configured to store milliseconds. So when you read the value from the db it will not include milliseconds, hence the times are slightly different.

One solution is to remove milliseconds from Time.now. You can do this like so `Time.now.change(usec: 0)`. This should fix the error in the tests.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your times are very close but not quite equal. They are probably off by a few fractions of a second.

One solution to issues like this is a testing gem called [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop). It gives you the ability to mock Time.now so that it will temporarily return a specific value that you can use for comparisons.

Comment: Funny enough, Timecop was the first savior I thought of when I encountered this issue, yet it didn't help. Funny.

Comment: The issue is that even if you freeze time, it doesn't help - probably because of some infinitesimal drift that whatever arithmetic is at play can't reliably compare. However, when I set the time to a particular moment of my choosing with the miliseconds rounded, off, then it works, ie `Timecop.freeze`  fails and `Timecop.freeze Time.parse("2016-09-13 18:26:09 +0200")` works`